# The timeout for reading from the SSL socket pauses when the screen is off

Tags: java, android, sockets, ssl

I set the timeout for read from `SSLSocket` 2 minutes. But `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed` do not come while the phone's screen is off. When I turn on the screen, the timeout starts working.
This is the receive method code:

```
public byte[] recieve() {
byte[] result = null;

try {
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
mSocket.setSoTimeout(120000);
InputStream socketOutStream = mSocket.getInputStream();
Log.d("xxx", "Waiting response's length...");
socketOutStream.read(bb.array(), 0, 4);
int length = bb.getInt();
Log.d("xxx", String.format("  Response length: %d bytes", length));
result = new byte[length];
Log.d("xxx", String.format("Waiting response..", length));
int bytesRead = socketOutStream.read(result);
if (bytesRead == length) {
    Log.d("xxx", String.format("  Bytes actually read: %d", length));
    return result;
}
else if (bytesRead != 0 && bytesRead < length) {
    length -= bytesRead;
    while (length > 0) {
        int bytesActuallyRead = socketOutStream.read(result, bytesRead, length);
        length -= bytesActuallyRead;
        bytesRead += bytesActuallyRead;
    }
    return result;
}

} catch(IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
Log.e("xxx", String.format("Socket error: %s", e.getMessage()));
}

return null;
}
```

My application should work when the screen is off. As I understand, the method `read` is blocking. Can I make my custom timeout? How can I solve the problem?

Comment: You could throw most of that away and use `DataInputStream.readFully()`.

Comment: What will it give? Will work the timeout for read when the screen is off?